# The function executes again even after coming out of the for loop in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, treeview, treenode

I am using `TreeView` in my web project to display the menus. Below is the function which I am using to find the level of the nodes.

```
int FindLevel(string id, int level)
{
    int dj = 0;
    for (dj = 0; dj < dTable.Rows.Count; dj++)
    {
        string id2 = dTable.Rows[dj]["TCode"].ToString();
        string parent1 = dTable.Rows[dj]["TGroup"].ToString();
        if (id == id2)
        {
            if (parent1 == "")
            {
                return level;
            }
            else
            {
                level += 1;
                FindLevel(parent1, level);
            }
        }
    }
    return level;
}

private void PopulateRootLevel()
{
    dTable = getConnection.GetAdapterDatatable("uspMenuGet 'ALL','HVV',0,0,0", csGlobal.getMainConnection);
    int di = 0;
    for (di = 0; di < dTable.Rows.Count; di++)
    {
        string id1 = dTable.Rows[di]["TCode"].ToString();
        dTable.Rows[di]["TLevel"] = FindLevel(id1, 0);
    }
}
```

Let us assume that when dj=10, the first if condition satisfies and comes out of the for loop on returning the level.
But, after coming out of the for loop, the FindLevel function executes again until dj reaches Datatable count.

Answer (score 0):

**return** will return value but Loop will continue.

Use **break** to exit the loop.

Comment: I used the break. But, it is not breaking the loop. It just breaks the current iteration and continues.